# How to use ng-if in ionic2 in html template file

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic2

if records is found i want to display the records otherwise to display the no records found.

i have used following code

```
<div  ng-if="program.videourl">
<video  width="100%" controls="controls" preload="metadata"  webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" class="videoPlayer"><source [src]="program.videourl" type="video/mp4" autostart="false" /></video>
</div>

<!--if no records found under programs -->
<div  ng-if="!program.videourl">
    No records found .
</div>
```

But it displays both conditions.is there any mistake
Please correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `*ngIf`:

```
<div *ngIf="program.videourl">
```